# how to add a password to a button event which cause the event to proceed or fail

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a `Xcode` project which is a questionnaire, that has a few questions in and buttons that pass the data selected from one view to the other using segue tags.

At the end of the questionnaire I have a show data button in which will take the admin to the page with the data on as a whole, my issue is anyone can trigger the show data event and I was wondering how would I go about adding a password so that only the admin can see the data.

I've looked online and haven't seen anything that relates to what I need to happen, most things online go over creating a sign up page.

```
@IBAction func DataReveal(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        ID = ID2.text
        date = date2.text
        Answer1 = answ1.text
        Answer2 = answ2.text
    }
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Link6", sender: self)
    }
```

This takes the results from the other pages and passes them to the page that has the show data button, I just need to add password protection to it so only the password holder can see the data.

Comment: you need to ask password if that password is correct than you want show next scenario or data? Am i right?

Comment: how would I go about setting up the password to start with and

Answer (score 2):

You need to Show UIAlert Action with textfield for pick password from user and match text with your password from Coredata,keychain or with API whatever you want.

UIAlert with textfield code is

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Test Title", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addTextField { textField in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Password"
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }
    let confirmActionBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { [weak alertController] _ in
        guard let alertController = alertController, let textField = alertController.textFields?.first else { return }
        print("Password is \(String(describing: textField.text))")

        // Just compare Entered String in textfield with your original password password

        //if password is matched push or segue your required controller
    }
    alertController.addAction(confirmActionBtn)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Show this alert from your Button IBAction

Comment: cheers for the help, ill give it a go and see where I end up.

Comment: how do I go about setting a password for it to check against and if its correct how would I go about performing the segue to the last page

Comment: how do I go about setting a password for it to check against... shoked.. i have mention it in my question if you have saved your password in coredata or have API for this.. you need SignUp Page or same like this Alert box to get password from user and set it in your coredata or API whatever you want

Comment: This is not a platform for give you All code. This is learning platform.

Comment: I understand what this platform is and that its not here for people to give you the code straight up. with the alert textfield can I not just compare that to a variable that's set with the password.